# Is there a convention for adding .pc files for pkg-config?

Tags: libraries, pkg-config

I installed a library via apt but it added no .pc file to the pkg-config dir. When I built another manually it got added. Is there a convention for libs automatically creating a .pc file and if so when and how is it done?

Answer (score 9):

Like .so symlinks and .h header files, the .pc files are not be shipped in libXXX debian packages, but in the accompanying libXXX-dev packages as they are only useful when developing against that library.

Comment: It was the dev package I installed via apt, yet no .pc file?

Comment: (package - libboost1.42-dev)

Comment: Boost doesn't ship .pc files as it installs headers etc. in /usr/, so the compiler will find them without extra flags.

Comment: Ditto.  Not everything uses pkg-config.  Some of boost does require a linker flag, but you don't need a .pc file for any of this -- altho if you google "libboost pkg-config" you'll find some debate from downstream packagers.

Comment: I had to add '-lboost_filesystem' flag when compiling my src for that lib, is that expected?

Comment: *for that lib - I meant 'with that lib'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should always do that.

For users who use your library, `pkg-config --libs --cflags libmtp` is always easier than appending these flags manually, and they don't need to guess the dependency of your library.

And I don't think there's a way automating it.